# Built in ema function in boolean expression

Tags: pine-script, boolean-expression

I came across this expression.

```
longExit() => ema(close, 80) and rsi(close, 2) >= 80
```

I assume this is a function definition which returns a boolean. When does the first node (ema(close, 80)) evaluate to be true? The documentation says that the built-in ema function returns a float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a wrong use. It will evaluate to be `true` pretty much all the time except when that node returns `0` which is `false` in `boolean`.